# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: linq, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, clean-architecture

I am trying to implementation clean architecture in netcore and I have Runtime Error
InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

In the WebUI I have Match controller and ViewAllMatch Action like this

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ViewAllMatch()
        {
            var matches = await _mediator.Send(new GetMatchesDetail());
            return View(matches);
        }
```

In the application Layer I have A queries like this:

```
public class GetMatchesDetail : IRequest<IEnumerable<MatchesDetail>>
    {
    }
    public class MatchesDetail
    {
        public string MatchId { get; set; }
        public int MatchNumer { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateMatch { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan TimeMatch { get; set; }
        public int MatchYear { get; set; }
        public string SeasonId { get; set; }
        public string Round { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// Set value to Qualified for Qualified and Final for Final Round
        /// </summary>
        public string Stage { get; set; }
        public string SubStage { get; set; }
        public string HTeam { get; set; }
        public string HTeamCode { get; set; } //For Flag get from Table Team from Foreign Key TeamName
        public int HGoal { get; set; }
        public int GGoal { get; set; }
        public string GTeam { get; set; }
        public string GTeamCode { get; set; }
        public string WinNote { get; set; }
        public string Stadium { get; set; }
        public string Referee { get; set; }
        public long Visistors { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class GetMatchesHandler : IRequestHandler<GetMatchesDetail, IEnumerable<MatchesDetail>>
    {
        private readonly IMatchRepository _matchRepository;
       
        public GetMatchesHandler(IMatchRepository matchRepository)
        {
            _matchRepository = matchRepository;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<MatchesDetail>> Handle(GetMatchesDetail request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var matchlistview = await _matchRepository.GetMatchDetailAsync();

            return matchlistview;
        }
    }
```

And the code for matchRepository to get all the match in Infastructure like this.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MatchesDetail>> GetMatchDetailAsync()
        {
            var matchDetailList = (from match in _context.Matches
                                   join team1 in _context.Teams on match.HTeam equals team1.TeamName
                                   join team2 in _context.Teams on match.GTeam equals team2.TeamName
                                   join season in _context.Seasons on match.SeasonId equals season.SeasonId
                                   select new
                                   {
                                       match.MatchId,
                                       match.MatchNumber,
                                       match.DateMatch,
                                       match.TimeMatch,
                                       match.MatchYear,
                                       match.SeasonId,
                                       season.SeasonName,
                                       match.Round,
                                       match.Stage,
                                       match.SubStage,
                                       match.HTeam,
                                       HTeamCode = team1.TeamCode,
                                       match.HGoal,
                                       match.GGoal,
                                       match.GTeam,
                                       GTeamCode = team2.TeamCode,
                                       match.WinNote,
                                       match.Stadium,
                                       match.Referee,
                                       match.Visistors

                                   });

            return (IEnumerable<MatchesDetail>)await matchDetailList.ToListAsync();
        }
```

Full code have been upload to Github at https://github.com/nguyentuananh921/Betting.git.
for more detail.

Thanks for your help.
I am so confuse about model in clean architech when i have more entities and the model I want to view in the WebUI contain many entities in domain.

Comment: try it without casting, `List<T>` is an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: Please tell me more clearly where to try? In Repository or in the Request from mediatr

Comment: in `GetMatchDetailAsync()` return the value without casting

Comment: Because you are trying to cast `List<anonymous>` to `IEnumerable<MatchesDetail>`, which is totally wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I have Modify public IEnumerable GetMatchDetailAsync() like that.

```
public IEnumerable<MatchesDetail> GetMatchDetailAsync()
    {          

        #region TryOther way
        var matchQuery = (from match in _context.Matches
                               join team1 in _context.Teams on match.HTeam equals team1.TeamName
                               join team2 in _context.Teams on match.GTeam equals team2.TeamName
                               join season in _context.Seasons on match.SeasonId equals season.SeasonId
                               select new
                               {
                                   #region selectResult
                                   //Remove to clear Select what I want to get.
                                   #endregion

                               });
        MatchesDetail matchesDetail = new MatchesDetail();
        List<MatchesDetail> retList = new List<MatchesDetail>();
        //IEnumerable<MatchesDetail> retList;
        foreach (var item in matchQuery)
        {
            #region ManualMapping
                matchesDetail.MatchId = item.MatchId;
                //other field mapping

            #endregion
            retList.Add(matchesDetail);
        }
        #endregion
        return retList;

    }
```

And it work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What a hassle. Why not just `select new MatchesDetail` (instead of `select new`)?